# When do DOM elements become live and their events are hooked and (can) fire

Tags: javascript, web, dom, event-handling

For instance an `HTMLImageElement` has events it can trigger on load success or failure.

These events seem to trigger asynchronously even if the image is not added to a document, or is part of a fragment. They only seem to be suppressed if the image is added to a `<template>` *before the event can fire*:

```js
// onerror will fire
const image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = '0'
image.onerror = () => log("detached");

// onerror will fire
const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
const fragmentImage = document.createElement('img');
fragmentImage.src = '0';
fragmentImage.onerror = () => log("fragment");
fragment.appendChild(fragmentImage);

// onerror will *not* fire
const template = document.createElement('template');
const templateImage = document.createElement('img');
template.content.appendChild(templateImage);
templateImage.src = '0';
templateImage.onerror = () => log("template first");

// onerror will fire
const templateImage2 = document.createElement('img');
templateImage2.src = '0';
templateImage2.onerror = () => log("template last");
template.content.appendChild(templateImage2);
```

I tried looking at the WhatWG spec, but didn't find anything which seemed relevant, or at least not clearly. While [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) precisely describes steps to perform when updating `loading` or calling `decode()`, it doesn't seem to really explain the loaded process and how the various events are invoked when `src` (or `srcset` I guess) is interacted with.

Comment: Please add language and/or framework tag